# Поиск пути к определенным данным в большом json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Есть большой json, нужно для python найти путь к определенному ключу. Глазами просмотреть весь json, даже в читабельном формате не представляется возможным, как легко определить путь к нужному ключу? Чтобы на выходе иметь что то вроде `['key1']['key2']['key3']...ets...['target_key']`

Comment: воспользоваться поиском в глубину \ ширину?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поиск по вашему json как по дереву:

просматриваем наличие ключа в текущем узле, если найден = успех, иначе повторить для всех дочерних узлов.

```py
import json

raw = '{"foo": {"bar": {"baz": {"search_key": "value", "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}'
data = json.loads(raw)


def search(search_key, search_tree, parent_key=None):
    if search_key in search_tree:
        yield f'{parent_key if parent_key else ""}["{search_key}"]', search_tree[search_key]
    else:
        for sub_key, sub_tree in search_tree.items():
            if isinstance(sub_tree, dict):
                yield from search(search_key, sub_tree, f'{parent_key if parent_key else ""}["{sub_key}"]')


for found in search('search_key', data):
    print(found)
```

`('["foo"]["bar"]["baz"]["search_key"]', 'value')`

P.S. Так же, если есть дополнительная информация о том, что искомый ключ, например не может находиться в определенных ветках, то поиск может быть улучшен за счет исключения этих случаев из просмотра по ним.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через сторонний модуль [dpath](https://github.com/dpath-maintainers/dpath-python) (установка `pip install dpath`)

Пример:

```
import json
import dpath.util


raw = '{"foo": {"bar": {"baz": {"search_key": "value", "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}, "other_key": "bad val"}'
data = json.loads(raw)

print(dpath.util.get(data, '**/search_key'))
# value

print(dpath.util.search(data, '**/search_key'))
# {'foo': {'bar': {'baz': {'search_key': 'value'}}}}

print(list(dpath.util.search(data, '**/search_key', yielded=True)))
# [('foo/bar/baz/search_key', 'value')]
```